# How to tackle error raised in 1 WFE out of 3 WFE?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, error, debugging, load-balancing, front-end

Someone had asked this question but proper answer is not known, can anyone say what will be the proper answer for this?
We have a SharePoint application spread on 3 WFE server. Now one component is creating trouble in only one specific front-end server, not in other 2 WFEs. So error is in 1 WFE while other 2 WFE are fine. How to tackle this situation? What steps we should take in this case?

Comment: It depends on which component have problem. e.g. for search component. First we need to remove the problem WFE from topology, reinstall the problem component, and then put it back to the topology.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have a farm. I would presume that you should be looking on the server that holds central admin. Goto the logs and check there, the logs is located within the hive files:

sharepoint 2007

> C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server
>   Extensions\12\LOGS

sharepoint 2010

> C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server
>   Extensions\14\LOGS

sharepoint 2013

> C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server
>   Extensions\15\LOGS

As you have noted that your tapology is setup for load balancing and i presume that your search is also split over the three. I presume that wfe 1 and 2 are purely front end whilst wfe 3 is central admin?

if it is the case than look on wfe 3 where central admin lies and look in the hive logs for errors. This will show any errors across all three. You can also check out the event viewer logs:

> start -> administrator tools -> event veiwer.

within event viewer -> expand 'windows log' -> application

this will show you errors correlating to the server! so if you have an issue with a wsp that you deployed on wfe 1 than it would show up on event viewer on wfe 1 but the majority of errors would be on your central admin server!

if you do get any issues with load balancing on your server than usually it would show up in your hive log files on you central admin server and it usually states a server name thats having the issue!

Say that you have an issue where your site is setup like yours to be load balanced. Usually if wfe1 fails than wfe2 would be the one that displays the info. If you deployed a wsp to wfe1 than it would show an error on the page! the page still loads as you have wfe2 up but it might not be the same as wfe1 and its hosted by central admin server on wfe3. As you can see all is running fine but your site is missing webparts or erroring when you load a page or missing data ect, to me that indicats that there is somthing wrong with one of the servers and going to the central admin server usually would show the offending server that has failed on load balancing.

another senario is splitting up the search service application so that the load of crawlig large front end would be split over three server to blannce the load from the indexing. This is common practice and if one fails would show up in the hive log files, it would also show up in the search service in central admin search service applications where one of the index partitions has failed and is offline!

check this link and zoom in. Look under cross-farm services. Here you can see what would be able to split over multiple servers for load balancing and other services only allowed on one server. Either way they are all accessible from central admin so would make sense if there was to be any issues with these applications they would generate an error on the same server that central admin lives on!

http://zoom.it/yiYK#full

for more tapologies and setups refer here:

2013 but can also apply to 2010:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263199.aspx

2007 also applies to 2010:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263199(v=office.12).aspx

in my case i would deploy to the central admin server any wsp's, i would have as above services split over wfe's like search and have load balancing on. If one wfe was to go down it wouldnt be a big issue as i have deployed on central admin the wsp and should update both wfe's. If central admin goes down than it wouldnt matter as everything goes down and you would get a 404 or more likely a 503 error ;) , error checking would be on central admin server as central admin server hosts all services and is accessible from central admin. If there was an issue with one wfe it would show as an issue on central admin and thats where i would as an admin to goto error page on central admin to check error out and check out the logs on central admin and then the offending front end server and check the local error logs for that server, event viewer. Event viewer is usually local to that server and would show any issues.